# Equivalent definitions of an event being mutually independent of other events

Tags: probability

The notes I'm reading make the following definition:

> Given events $E_1, \ldots , E_n \subset \Omega$ and a subset $J \subset [n]$, the event $E_i$ is said to be *mutually independent* of $\{ E_j : j \in J \}$ if for all choices of disjoint subsets $J_1, J_2 \subset J$,
>   \begin{equation}
> \Pr \left[E_i \cap \bigcap_{j_1 \in J_1} E_{j_1} \cap \bigcap_{j_2 \in J_2}    \overline{E_{j_2}} \right] = \Pr\left[E_i\right] \Pr \left[ \bigcap_{j_1 \in J_1} E_{j_1} \cap \bigcap_{j_2 \in J_2}    \overline{E_{j_2}} \right]
> \end{equation}

In other words, it is a definition that requires independence in regards to intersections of events but also intersections of complements of events. What is bothering me is I feel that the "complements" part of the condition is unnecessary. I'm guessing the author chose to add it just to make his work easier down the road.

I.e., I believe the following would be an equivalent definition:

> Given events $E_1, \ldots , E_n \subset \Omega$ and a subset $J \subset [n]$, the event $E_i$ is said to be *mutually independent* of $\{ E_j : j \in J \}$ if for all choices of a subset $J_1 \subset J$,
>   $$\Pr \left[E_i \cap \bigcap_{j_1 \in J_1} E_{j_1}  \right] = \Pr\left[E_i\right] \Pr \left[ \bigcap_{j_1 \in J_1} E_{j_1} \right]$$

I wasn't able to come up with a counterexample, so now I'm trying to prove equivalency. It seems to me that the natural method would be to prove that, given the equation in the second (my) definition holds for $E_i$, show that the left side of the equation in the first definition equals the right side. I've been struggling to make progress. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you construct a bijection between two probability spaces such that complements in the original space correspond to "positive" events in the new space?  Obviously, this bijection would be different for each choice $J_1, J_2$.

Comment: It would be interesting to me to see if this also follows when there are an infinite number of events $E_1, E_2, E_3, \ldots$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A,B$ be arbitrary events in the same probability space.

Take $\def\indep{\perp\hspace{-1.5ex}\perp} A\indep B$ as a premise.

That is that the events are independent; which means exactly that: 
$$\def\P{\mathop{\mathsf P}}\P(A\cap B)=\P(A)\P(B)$$

Use this premise, and the Rules of Probability for Complements, to show:

$$\P(A\cap B^\complement)=\P(A)\P(B^\complement)$$

And therefor proving that $A\indep B^\complement$ is a logical consequence of $A\indep B$.

Everything else is mathematical induction.